# Prove that a PDA with k stacks is Turing-Recognisable

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines, pushdown-automaton

This was once a homework, but I'm now using it for revision purposes; But there is no solution for this problem. Any advice would be much appreciated.

The question asks:
"Let a k-PDA be a pushdown automaton with access to k stacks. A 1-PDA is a standard PDA, and you have seen that 2-PDAs can recognise any Turing-recognisable language. Show that, for any k ≥ 0, any language recognised be a k-PDA is Turing-recognisable."

Directly copy&pasted, Could anyone help with this problem? Also, I feel like this is incorrectly written but I'm not sure what would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we can simulate k-pda movements by a multi-tape(k-tape) Turing machine whose movements can be simulated by a standard Turing machine.